# How to implement state restoration for observed property

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing, state-restoration

I have an Document-based Cocoa application for which I want to implement state restoration. Specifically, my subclass of NSDocument contains a controller object that needs to preserve some of its attributes. The problem is that one of the window controllers registers itself as observer of the controller *before* the controller has been restored. Thus, when the controller is restored the app throws an exception because it tries to deallocate the default controller while it is already being observed.

*An instance 0x600000001ba0 of class DataController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.*

I created a minimal example that reproduces the problem. The structure is as follows:

```
RestorationExample
|-> Document.h
|-> Document.m // Custom subclass of NSDocument, has DataController property
|-> DataController.h
|-> DataController.m // Controller that needs to be restored
|-> MainWindowController.h
|-> MainWindowController.m // Observes self.document.dataController
|-> MainWindow.xib // Window controlled by MainWindowController
```

You can download the sample project from here to make it easier to set everything up: https://github.com/mpflanzer/restoration_example

The **`Document`** simply creates the `MainWindowController`

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers {
    [self addWindowController:[[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"]];
}
```

and encodes/restores its dataController property

```
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSLog(@"Document::encode");
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:self.dataController forKey:@"dataController"];
}

- (void)restoreStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSLog(@"Document::restore");
    [super restoreStateWithCoder:coder];
    self.dataController = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"dataController"];
}
```

The **`MainWindowController`** registers itself as observer in the `windowDidLoad` method and de-registers in `windowWillClose`. *Is that how to do it correctly? Or are there other function that should be used to add or remove observers?*

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"MainWindowController::windowDidLoad");
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [((Document*)self.document).dataController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [((Document*)self.document).dataController removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataOffset"];
}
```

Currently **`DataController`** doesn't do anything special as the app already fails. Later it obviously has to implement `initWithCoder` to restore its attributes.

When I run the example (and state restoration is triggered) I get the following log output:

```
2017-04-19 18:57:54.846297+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Document::init
2017-04-19 18:57:54.846440+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] DataController::init
2017-04-19 18:57:54.887825+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Document::readFromData
2017-04-19 18:57:54.953205+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] MainWindowController::windowDidLoad
2017-04-19 18:57:54.953386+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Change data offset: 0
2017-04-19 18:57:54.957346+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Document::restore
2017-04-19 18:57:54.958678+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Ignoring exception raised in void _NSPersistentUIExecuteDispatchedBlock(void (^)(void)): An instance 0x600000001c20 of class DataController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x60000002ae00> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000056050: Observer: 0x600000088a70, Key path: dataOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000005e9c0>
)
2017-04-19 18:57:59.592119+0100 RestorationExample[16829:1225236] Document::encode
```

There problem is that `makeWindowControllers` and thus `windowDidLoad` is invoked before the `Document` has been restored. Given that order the `MainWindowController` will register as observer and only afterwards the `Document` will try to restore its `dataController` property to the saved state.

Is there something wrong how I implemented the state restoration? Or in the way I add/remove the observer? I would have expected that the `Document` is restored first and only afterwards `makeWindowControllers` is invoked.

Comment: "I would have expected that the Document is restored first and only afterwards `makeWindowControllers` is invoked." I've never tried this on macOS, though I do know something about the analog on iOS. However, it seems to me that you proved that what you "would have expected" not so. So isn't the answer just "stop expecting that"? Don't register the observer until after the observer is in place.

Comment: But where would that be? I can't think of a method of the `MainWindowController` that is called after the document has been restored. The init methods and windowDidLoad seem to be called before state restoration takes place. I'm wondering if my design is wrong and the window controller is not supposed to register itself as observer.

Comment: Don't restore the controller, restore its properties. Or maybe it works if you put the controller in the observed keypath.

Comment: Well, that's kind of what I was thinking of. This is a _document_ restoration, so it's a little hard for me to imagine what business of the _window_ controller it is. The _view_ controller, yes. But the whole point of documents and view controllers is to separate that kind of thing _away_ from the window controller (and the app delegate). So it seems to me that your functionality is in the wrong place. However, the document could always post a notification when everything is ready, if you want to let the w.c. know — or the document could _register_ the w.c.

Comment: @Willeke But, in terms of OOP, shouldn't every object handle only its own attributes? In my case the the `DataController` would thus restore its attribute and the document would restore its `dataController` property. I don't see why the document should restore the attributes of its properties (as they might not even provide setters).

@matt The `MainWindowController` doesn't really take place in the restoration itself. It just observes a property of (a property of) the document. And that causes problems during the restoration process.

Comment: The document calls `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` and  `restoreStateWithCoder:` of the controller and the controller encodes and restores its own properties.

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean. Yes, that works of course. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.